# Which class of Dynamical Systems is governed by Lagrangian Dynamics?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, complex-systems, dissipation

Lagrangian formalism is a technique using which we can obtain the time evolution of a dynamical system. Given a dynamical system, can we say whether or not we can write down a Lagrangian (solving it is another thing) i.e. can we say that a given dynamical system is in the realm of lagrangian dynamics (or is it invalid to ask such a question)?

Comment: Related, and  possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1058/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3500/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4749/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451 and links therein.